# What is so special about "Twitter Bootstrap"?

Tags: website-design, design, responsive-design

I have seen Twitter [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and Yahoo [purecss](http://purecss.io/) but I don't understand why they are becoming industry standards. People tend to directly use them for their project without thinking of something unique for their project. I would like to understand why using these framework can enhance your designs.

Answer (score 6):

They're not used for the sake of design, but rather for fast implementation. Bootstrap allows developers to quickly prototype in HTML+CSS. Most projects will require at least *some* kind of grid system and CSS resets, so bootstrap and purecss fill that gap.

Comment: So, does that mean that these frameworks are not for designers but rather for developers?

Comment: @AnkitSharma - ish. It's more for designers and developers to quickly prototype with functionality that can't easily be mocked with Axure and the like.

Answer (score 3):

We use frameworks because modularity is great. Frameworks lets us focus on solving unique tasks, not on reinventing the wheel.

There is no reason why a developer should have to retype the same lines of code over and over. This costs time/money, it is boring, and it is hard to maintain.